# Jquery Open Accordion based on URL anchor hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a FAQ accordion.
Each question has a class name of q with id of q1 or q2 or q3.
Each answer has a class name of a.

When the url has a anchor tag /faq#q2, I want the q2 to be triggered. I have the below code but its the not working.

I think the line that caused it not working is: if (hash) $(.q[id$="+hash+"]).trigger('click'); but i can't figure out whats wrong.

```js
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    
 $(".a").hide().first().show();
    $(".q:first").addClass("active");
 
    $('#accordion').find('.q').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".a").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

      //Find anchor hash and open
      var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );
      if (hash) $(.q[id$="+hash+"]).trigger('click'); 
    });
  });
```

```css
  .q {cursor: pointer;}
  .a {display: none;}
  .q.active + .accordion-content {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="q" id="q1">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="a">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue <a href="#q2" onclick="setTimeout('history.go(0);',800);">Open Accordion 2</a> molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="q" id="q2">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="a">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="q" id="q3">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="a">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - you've lost single or double quotes with your jQuery selector. And if I understand correctly - you want something like this?

```
if (hash) {
  var element = $(hash);
  if (element.length) {
    element.trigger('click');
  }
}
```

Update (http://jsfiddle.net/6hzby0aa/):

```js
// Hide all panels
$(".a").hide();

// Show first panel by default
$(".q:eq(0)").next(".a").show();

// Get hash from query string. You can put there "#q1", "#q2" or something else for test
var hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash) {
    // Get panel header element
    var requestedPanel = $(hash);
    if (requestedPanel.length) {
        // Hide all panels
        $(".a").hide();
        // Show requested panel
        requestedPanel.next(".a").show();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="q" id="q1">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="a">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue <a href="#q2" onclick="setTimeout('history.go(0);',800);">Open Accordion 2</a> molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="q" id="q2">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="a">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="q" id="q3">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="a">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically I just want Question 2 to be clicked open automatically when user load a url with #q2.

Comment: you mean like this?
if (hash) $('.q[id="+hash+"]').click();

Comment: @user3108698 I really don't know why you're still using ".q[id=...]" as selector. window.location.hash will return "#q1". It is actually yours element id.

Comment: Im confused, Can you please provide a complete code.

Comment: @user3108698 Yes. Please see my updated answer. Sorry, I've got not enough reputation for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final Code. Thanks to @Andrew Orlov

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        // Hide all panels
        $(".a").hide();

        // Show first panel by default
        $(".q:eq(0)").next(".a").show();
        $(".q:first").addClass("active");

        // Get hash from query string
        var hash = window.location.hash;

        if (hash) {
            // Get panel header element
            var requestedPanel = $(hash);
            if (requestedPanel.length) {
                // Hide all panels
                $(".a").hide();
                $('.q').removeClass("active"); // remove active
                // Show requested panel
                requestedPanel.next(".a").show();
                requestedPanel.addClass("active"); //add active
            }
        };


        $('body').find('.q').click(function() {
            //Expand or collapse this panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('600');

            $('.q').removeClass("active"); // remove active
            $(this).addClass("active"); // add active

            //Hide the other panels
            $(".a").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```