# Unable to prevent accordion automatically collapse clicking on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have designed collapsible accordion. Its working fine. Problem is when click on submit button the accordion is collapsing automatically without clicking on the plus or minus which is used to collapse and uncollapse. In JS code i have used stopPropagation but its not working. Its should not be collapsed automatically without clicking on the plus or minus symbol. I want to keep accordion open after clicking on the Apply button.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    // Add minus icon for collapse element which is open by default
    $(".collapse.in").each(
      function() {
        $(this).siblings(".panel-heading").find(
          ".glyphicon").addClass(
          "glyphicon-minus").removeClass(
          "glyphicon-plus");

      });

    // Toggle plus minus icon on show hide of collapse element
    $(".collapse #btnSave").on(
      'show.bs.collapse',
      function(e) {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon")
          .removeClass("glyphicon-plus")
          .addClass("glyphicon-minus");
        e.stopPropagation();
      }).on(
      'hide.bs.collapse',
      function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon")
          .removeClass("glyphicon-minus")
          .addClass("glyphicon-plus");

      });
    e.stopPropagation();

  });

$("#startDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $("#endDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Set other min, default to today
  }
});

$("#endDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  endDate: true,
  todayHighlight: true, //today highlighted with different color
  minDate: 0, //to show current date

  numberOfMonths: 1, //to display number of months ex: 1 month or multiple months

  onSelect: function(dateStr) {

    var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate'); //to select highest date
    var start = $("#startDate").datepicker("getDate"); //get an start date using inbuilt method of getDate
    var end = $("#endDate").datepicker("getDate"); //get an end date using inbuilt method of getDate

    var days = ((end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1); //differnce calculation start date and enddate
    $("#noofDays").val(days); //calculated number of days

  }

});
```

```css
.panel-default>.panel-heading {
 border-color: black;
}

.bs-example {
 margin: 20px;
 font-weight: 700px;
}

.control-label {
 font-size: 11px;
 padding-top: 4px;
}

.form-control {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 27px;
 padding: 6px 6px;
 font-size: 10px;
}

.form-group {
 margin-top: 12px;
}

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
 text-align: justify;
 text-align-last: center;
}

#pls {
 font-size: 10px;
 float: right;
}

hr {
 height: 1px;
 color: #123455;
 background-color: #123455;
 border: none;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all {
 background-color: #123455;
}

#btnSave {
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: #90EE90;
 border-color: #ccc;
 color: black;
}

#btnCancel {
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: #FFA500;
 border-color: #ccc;
 color: black;
}

#btnS {
 background-color: #90EE90;
 border-color: #ccc;
 color: black;
}

#btnC {
 margin-right: 5px;
 background-color: #FFA500;
 border-color: #ccc;
 color: black;
}

.panel-footer {
 padding: 30px 15px;
}

#textAlign {
 text-align: center;
}

#remark {
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-size: 10px;
}
#notificationBell{

color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/jquery.ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
<!-- jQuery Popup css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <form role="form" name="leaveForm" id="leaveForm">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">

          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <span style="font-weight: 700;">L </span>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="pls" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span> &nbsp;
            </a>

          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">Leave Type <span
              class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <select class="form-control" required>
                      <option selected hidden value="">Type</option>
                      <option>Lee</option>
                      <option> Le</option>
                    </select>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">L<span
              class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="leaveBalance" id="leaveBalance" placeholder="Le" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">St<span
              class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">En<span
              class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" id="endDate" placeholder="End Date" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;"> No o<span
              class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noofDays" id="noofDays" placeholder="No of days" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">R</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <textarea rows="1" class="form-control" style="resize: none;" id="reason" placeholder=""></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <br />
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-11">
              <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Apply</button>
              <button type="reset" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">Cancel</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to kept it open after "btnSave" clicked, correct?

Comment: What are you doing on save button. Ajax?

Comment: @saActionExactly.

Comment: @CodeThing Post method in spring not using Ajax.

Comment: Please can anybody help me out.

Comment: why are you requesting to two versions of bootstrap? 3.1.0 and 3.3.7... Also, the first one is requested before jquery.

Comment: one more thing: there's an error occurring in your script. I think it's just a tiny mistake. The "e.stopPropagation()" was placed outside of the event's trigger "hide.bs.collapse"

Comment: so, just to clarify: you don't use AJAX, your form submit is refreshing the page and starting it with your form collapsed, that's it?

Comment: @Kiko GaricaYes correct

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); - i misplaced this event i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I'm assuming you can't deal with back-end languages (like PHP or Python) so I'm limited to front-end only. I'll solve your problem with  a simple jQuery solution with [hash navigation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp).

Inspired by **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867527/4265572)**:

> [Andrew Orlov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572379/andrew-orlov) said
>
> ```
> var hash = window.location.hash;
> if (hash) {
>   var element = $(hash);
>   if (element.length) {
>     element.trigger('click');
>   }
> }
> ```

With this we can ask to the browser to trigger the click event based on the hash navigation. Just add this piece of code to your script and add `action="#collapseTrigger"` to your form, also replacing

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="pls" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span> &nbsp;
            </a>
```

to

```
<a id="collapseTrigger" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="pls" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span> &nbsp;
            </a>
```

This will result in something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pg2v5anc/4/

Please notice I'm forcing the element click because we can't submit the form at JSFiddle. But that'll be the result after sending. Is this what you need?

Comment: Problem here is accordion being uncollapsed even i refresh the page.

Comment: my basic state of accordion is collapsed.

Comment: @Learning do you have any link to check that? as we're dealing with form submition it's possible there're other errors happening.